# PC Security/monitered

Tags: security, spyware

Is there anyone who can tell me by looking at some setting from my laptop if I have spywear installed or being remotely controlled what do I have to check for please advise how I find out if I am being remotely controlled or monitered TIA ps please expline in simpelist terms any help or answer im not very good or technical on this sort of subject its driving me crazy will be very gratefull for any help thank you also how I set up surface pro to be complete admin and max security

Comment: I would run a Malwarebytes scan. It's free: https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/

Comment: Then destroy the computer with fire

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. If your laptop has been hacked in the way you are afraid of, it will be able to cover its tracks.  In order to be sure you would need to monitor traffic through your router - and this is not something doable on standard routers without a fair amount if skill.

Getting antimalware ( +1 for Malwarebytes) will scan and help detect most infections, but if you are at "paranoid about government level"  you would need to take your device to an expert to do offline forensics - and even that may not be 100% if there is a keyloggers.

If you think about it, the answer is obvious. No one is going to put a "this computer is hacked" marker and realistically expect an intruder to honour it.

Comment: You don't set up your surface pro for Max security. That would mean making it totally unusable. You take it to a trustworthy computer person and get them to install security best practice's like clean install, secure boot, bitlocker, ensuring good password hygiene, av protection and the minimum number of programs are installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever fear your system is compromised, use a Live System to clean it.
For this, you will need a pendrive, and a safe, uninfected system.
Really, make sure, you do NOT prepare this system on the infected or suspected host.

ESET Live SysRescue: https://www.eset.com/int/support/sysrescue/
Bitdefende Rescue: https://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-create-a-bitdefender-rescue-cd-627.html

**MAKE SURE TO PREPARE THIS LIVE SYSTEM FROM A DIFFERENT, SAFE SYSTEM!**

If I can say this as an advice, after having a full scan, I would do a full backup of your system and finally, reinstall the whole thing. Most malware infections can cause permanent damage to the system which may more or less visible. It's not like your programs won't run or things like that. But it can compromise system stability. Maintaining system stability and writing a clean piece of software is not exactly a priority to malware developers.

You have no clue how to backup a system? Just use an external hard drive, and copy over the important files. You can also use a fire and forget solution like [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com/). They offer a trial. Keep in mind, this is an internet based backup solution, so it can take a while to finish.

Good luck.